# Custom Report in alfresco?

Tags: alfresco, solr4, alfresco-webscripts

Currently i am generating a report (we are getting files are uploaded within a time stamp).
I am getting all files and folders.Iterating the result and checking created date one by one.That is taking too much time approx 8 min to revert with resuls.Can anyone tell me is there any alfresco report api that i can use? or using solr how to fetch the result?

Answer (score 0):

I like to follow an approach which is maybe not really orthodox. Usually, you don't want to report on all documents, only document using a specific type or aspect. So, what I do is to create a Java behaviour on onCreate, onUpdate and onDelete that updates a custom database with only the metadata that I'm interested in. Then, I can connect any OOTB reporting tools such as Pentaho, Jasper or Tableau. You have of couse some other traditional alternatives, such as:

- Using this module developed by a community member: http://fcorti.com/alfresco-audit-analysis-reporting/
- Or using the module provided by Alfresco: http://docs.alfresco.com/analytics/concepts/analytics-using.html

Comment: Thanks to reply @Ben Chevallereau  but i dont want any add-on that's why i wrote my service.Is there any way not to use add-on ?

Comment: Even if SolR is fast, each time that you'll request a massive # of items, it will take a bit of time... Look at that too, it could work for you and may be way faster: http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/intrans-metadata-query.html

Answer (score 0):

SOLR/Lucene is not an option, querying DB directly is not an option either (performance wise).

I would suggest using one of the options available (AAAR for instance) or developing something on your own following the same principles.

Comment: Thanks @Lista can you suggess how to implement AAAR Tool for my instance i am using alfresco webservices. share we are not using

Answer (score 0):

I did little bit investigation on this and found below link.

http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/tasks/audit-recording-values.html

I think you can user auditService in alfresco and get your things done.There are few alfresco webservices(related to audit) already available which will allow you to filter response.In case if you need to customize it , than you can create webscript and use auditService in it.

You can use below url for browsing all your alfresco webservice.

http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/index